# How to do this congruen e modulo problem

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

How do i compute this Compute $9^{53} mod77 $.

i tried raising various powers of 9 and i also tried using binomial theorem by writing 9 as 10-1 but couldnot get to the answer. How do i do this

Thanks

Comment: Do you know Euler's thereom?  And the Chinese remainder theorem? 9^6=2^6=1 mod 7 so 9^53=2^5=32=4 mod 7. And 9^10 = 1 mod 11 so 9^53 =9^3=-2^3=-8=3 mod 11. So 9^53 = 4 mod 7 AND 3 mod 11.  That residue class is 25.  9^53 =25 mod 77.

Comment: But rain powers should have worked. 9^2=4;9^8=-13,9^16=169=15;9^32=225=-6 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the method of repeated squaring. $53 = 32+16+4+1$, and
$$9^1\equiv9\mod{77}$$
$$9^2\equiv 4\mod{77}$$
$$9^4 \equiv 4^2 \equiv 16\mod{77}$$
$$9^8\equiv 16^2\equiv25\mod{77}$$
$$9^{16}\equiv 25^2\equiv 9 \mod{77}$$
$$9^{32}\equiv 9^2\equiv 4 \mod 77$$
And so
$$9^{53} \equiv 9^{32}9^{16}9^{4}9^1 \equiv 4\cdot 9 \cdot 16\cdot 9 \equiv 25 \mod{77}$$

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the Chinese Remainder Theorem. So compute modulo $7$
and $11$. First $9^{53}\equiv 2^{53}\pmod 7$. The powers of $2$ repeat with
period $3$ modulo $7$, so $2^{53}\equiv 2^2\equiv4\pmod7$. Also $9^{53}\equiv(-2)^{53}\pmod{11}$. This case requires a little more work.
But you find a small $b$ with $9^{53}\equiv b\pmod{11}$.

The Euclidean algorithm allows one to solve the pair of simultaneous congruences
$x\equiv 4\pmod7$ and $x\equiv b\pmod{11}$.

Comment: " This case requires a little more work. " not with Fermats Little Theorem that powers of 2 will repeat with period 10.